# How to reference a class in a different package in the same project

Tags: java

I've tried working through some similar questions but I'm not getting anywhere

I have a main class in a package called overview.

In that class I create a string
I then want to send the string to another class in a different package in the same project

In my main class I have:

```
package Overview
import Bravo.*;

//some code
String s;
///Some code
Bravo.mane(s)
```

In the recipient class I have

```
package Bravo;

public class mane {

    public mane(String s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

When I am in the sending class main I seem to be able to access the class (in that when I type Bravo. (it gives me the class available in that package) but I still get an error saying that Bravo cannot be resolved ( in main).

Comment: You'd probably get all the assistance you needed by using an IDE

Comment: Also, please read about [Naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: That's not how you call a constructor.  It would be `new mane(s)`.  Though I suspect there may be other problems here as well.  (Mutually-referencing packages doesn't seem like a good idea...)

Comment: I've got rid of the import Overview.*; but still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bravo.mane(s)
```

this is the place you are getting the error , you are calling the `constructor` of the `class`. you can't call the `constructor`. constructor will be `invoked` when you instantiate the object.

ex:- 
 `mane maneObj = new mane("string");`